# linq expression cannot contain lamba expressions exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

```
var app = (from p in Totali
    select p.TotalImponibile).ToString();
```

I tried to look on the internet, but I didn't find any solution.
It's just a select statement.
In the debugger I get "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions", and in my textbox I don't get any result

some more code in the same method

```
var app = (from p in Totali
    select p.TotalImponibile).ToString();

string app2 = (from p in Totali
    select p.TotalImponibile + p.TotaleIva).ToString();


txtPrezzoTotale.Text = (from p in Totali
    select p.TotalImponibile).ToString();
```

Comment: Without more code or context is hard to tell..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the result before calling any method like `ToString()`.

```
var totalImponibile = (from p in Totali
                      select p.TotalImponibile).FirstOrDefault();

if (totalImponibile != null)
{
   // now you can use safely..
   string result = totalImponibile.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify that you only want the first result. Try with `.FirstOrDefault()` to retrieve the first result:

```
var app = (from p in Totali
           select p.TotalImponibile).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

If this can be null, you should check for it.

Comment: Or you can use ElementAt(yourindex).